# How to convert array written string to a real array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, arrays, string

I have this :

```
var chart = {
   chart_bar : 
    data : [{label:"A", data:[[0, 5], [1, 1]]}]
}
```

`data` variable must be an array. I passed a variable through ajax. the value of the variable is `{label:"C", data:[[0, 4], [1, 3]]}` and I assign it in to `data` variable and then script doesn't work.

PHP:

```
function get_data(){
    echo '{label:"C", data:[[0, 4], [1, 3]]}';
}
```

javascript:

```
$.ajax({
    url : "..../get_data", //no problem with the url
    data: "data="+somedata,
    type: "post",
    success : function(data_chart){

        var chart = {
            chart_bar : 
            data : [ data_chart ] // and the program doesn't work
            init : function(){
                alert(data_chart.toSource()); // it says (new String("{label:"C", data:[[0, 4], [1, 3]]}")), so the data_chart is a string
            }
        }
    }
});
```

but if I set

```
        var chart = {
            chart_bar : 
            data : [ {label:"C", data:[[0, 4], [1, 3]]} ] // and the program works
            init ; function(){
                alert(this.data.toSource()); // it says [ {label:"C", data:[[0, 4], [1, 3]]} ], so this is an array
        }
```

How can `data_chart` variable be an array? Is there any way to convert string to an array without change the string value/text?

Comment: Use JSON to to share data between server and client.

Comment: What if you set your $.ajax "dataType" to "json"? [jQuery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax-settings)

Comment: I have tried this but you know that `{label:"C", data:[[0, 4], [1, 3]]}` is not well json formatted text, so the ajax returns error.

Answer (score 2):

set your ajax to have a property like `dataType:"json"` so it will automatically turn the returned string into an object, otherwise you would need to use `data_chart = JSON.parse(data_chart);`

PHP

```
function get_data(){
   //note this is not proper json format
   echo '{label:"C", data:[[0, 4], [1, 3]]}'; 
   //should be
   echo '{"label":"C","data":[[0,4],[1,3]]}';  
}
```

Also note you can use php's json_encode like `echo json_encode($objOrArray)` to echo out json string of an object or array

JS

```
$.ajax({
   url : "..../get_data", //no problem with the url
   data: "data="+somedata,
   type: "post",
   dataType:"json",
   success :
      function(data_chart){
         //if valid JSON string was returned from the php script data_chart will be an object
         var chart = {
            chart_bar : 
            data : [ data_chart ],
            init : function(){
               alert(data_chart.toSource()); 
            }
         }
      }
});
```

Comment: thanks,, i found the way. but how to make a string to be an integer in php? i have $jml = "2", i want it be $jml = 2.

Comment: @OkiErieRinaldi use `intval($jml)`, not that you need to though since both php and javascript try to coerce their variables to the type needed. So if you  do "2"*2 php and javascript will coerce the "2" to be 2.

Comment: oh ya,, i think intval() can't convert it. thanks again. now it works. :D

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet is to use PHP's json_encode() function to produce the data as properly formatted JSON, and then use JSON.parse() or @Patrick Evans's jQuery suggestion to read the data in your JS.

PHP:

```
$data = array();
$data['label'] = "C";
$data['data'] = [[0,4],[1,3]];
print json_encode($data);
```

Comment: thanks,, i found the way. but how to make a string to be an integer in php? i have $jml = "2", i want it be $jml = 2.